# jQuery SlideToggle, toggles several times with Wordpress Custom Posts

Tags: jquery, wordpress, slidetoggle, custom-post-type

I've made a template in wordpress that contains my portfolio generated with custom post type.
I am trying to make a slidetoggle effect when I hover over a portfolio image.

The problem is that when I hover an image it only shows my togglediv on the first item and it toggles several times. How do I fix this?

You can see the problem yourself at http://www.camillawestin.se

(Sorry if the code is a bit messy).

jQuery:

```
   $(".portfolio-item").hover(function () {
    $("#port-link").slideToggle("fast");
    });
```

Wordpress template:

```
 <?php
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'portfolio'
    );
    $portfolio = new WP_Query( $args );
    if( $portfolio->have_posts() ) {
        while( $portfolio->have_posts() ) {
            $portfolio->the_post();
            ?>

            <div class="portfolio-item">
            <a href="<?php meta('special-link'); ?>"><div class="port-image"><?php the_post_thumbnail();?></div></a>



                <div id="port-link">
                <div class="port-tags"><?php the_tags($sep); ?></div>
                <div class="port-click">Klicka för att se hemsidan</div>
                </div>


                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h3 class="port-title"><?php the_title() ?></h3></a>
                <!--<a target="_blank" href="<?php meta('special-link'); ?>">Link</a>-->
                <div class='content'>
                    <?php the_content() ?>
                </div>
                </div><!--portfolio-item-->
            <?php
        }
    }
    else {
        echo 'Oh uhm there is no portfolio here yet!';
    }
?>
```

CSS:

```
    .portfolio-item {float: left; padding: 9px;}

    #port-link { 
    display:none; 
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 282px;
    opacity: 0.9;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: -60px;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 38px;}
```

Comment: ID's must be unique. Use a class instead.

Comment: When I changed to a class on port-link at least it shows the box on every item, but they toggle all at the same time and still toggles several times..

Comment: Right, but that's improvement. Now, you need to instead of targeting them all by class, target the specific one that was hovered using `this`

Comment: I did something like this.. It seems wrong. I haven't been working a lot with jQuery before..

$(".portfolio-item").hover(function () {
$(this).parents(".port-link"). slideToggle("fast");
});

Comment: use `.closest(".port-link")` so that it'll also work if you hover over port-link.

Comment: $(".portfolio-item").hover(function () {
$(this).parents(".port-link").closest(".port-link"). slideToggle("fast");});

Doesn't work att all.

Comment: no .parents(), just .closest.

Comment: Like this? $(this).closest(".port-link"). slideToggle("fast");

Nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, id's must be unique, use a class instead. Next, you'll want to target only the port-link that is inside the area that was hovered.

```
$(".portfolio-item").hover(function () { 
    $(this).find(".port-link").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

Note however that .hover() is going away, it would need to be replaced with:

```
$(".portfolio-item").on("mouseenter mouseleave", function () { 
    $(this).find(".port-link").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

Comment: Thanks alot! Do you know how I can stop it from toggling up and down several times? I'm guessing it has something to do with the wordpress loop because the last item works great.

Comment: Sorry I'm an idiot. I placed the script inside the loop, of course it toggled over and over.. Thank you so much for the help.

Problem solved.